# How can I query what security labels exist on a table?

Tags: postgresql, anonymize

Using the `postgresql-anonymizer` Postgres extension I've set security labels for masking on a number of columns.

e.g.

`SECURITY LABEL FOR anon ON COLUMN "Customer"."firstName" IS 'MASKED WITH FUNCTION anon.fake_first_name()`

I want a way to query if it's been added, and see what the label is. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query `pg_seclabels` to find the table and columns the labels are assigned to.

`objname` will contain the table and column e.g. `"Users"."firstName"`, `label`, as the name gives away, will contain the label. e.g. `'MASKED WITH FUNCTION anon.fake_first_name()`

```
  SELECT objname, label
  FROM pg_seclabels
  WHERE provider = 'anon';
```